# How to call a Constructor of choice in parent (Super) class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor

I want the parameterized constructor(Constructor of choice) of the parent class to be called during inheritance.

But by default I'm getting the un-parameterized constructor.

```
class parent
{

    parent(int i){System.out.println("From parameterized constructor");}
    parent(){System.out.println("From Normal Constructore");}
}

class child extends parent
{
    child()
    {
    System.out.println("From child");
    }
}


public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        child c=new child();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please define what a parameterized constructor is?  How is it different from a constructor?

Comment: Have you read into the `super()` command?  It's used to initialize variables that the parent class would have.  Plus, you are creating a child class with the constructor with no parameters.

Comment: Take care of the Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an uppercase letter

Comment: You use `super(5)` for example. In other words: A) you do some more research B) ... you simple pass the required parameter ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default every constructor contains a call to `super()` as the first line unless specifically overridden. So in your case;

```
Child() {
    System.out.println("From child");
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Child() {
    super();
    System.out.println("From child");
}
```

Where `super()` is a reference to the default constructor of the parent class. To change it. You can do something like the following;

```
Child() {
    super(1);
    System.out.println("From child");
}
```

This should output something like

```
From parameterized constructor
From child
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Keep this in mind: you want to use a specific constructor, you need to actually call it.

Comment: FYI: you may want a constructor for your `child` class that is parametrized as well. The parameters need to come from somewhere and `super()` always has to be called in the first line. And one last tip: it is good practice to use capital letters for classes: `Child` instead of `child`. Then expressions like `Child child = new Child()` will be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you won't specify any constructor, it will take the default one (parameterless).
If you want a different one, you can call it by calling `super`:

```
child() {
    super(1);
    System.out.println("From child");
}
```